# Know coordinate of Z from XY value and angle

Tags: math, geometry, 2d

I am using XY coordinate of drawing to draw object using Ink. Now I have one requirement. I have one Object, which is slope of 30 degree and I need to write some text for e.g. 'ABC' on the slope. What I have is XY coordiate and Angle and I want to find the Z from this information. Could you please suggest me some proper way to find the Z from the given information?

While Marking on the slope I need to down the Z axis to remain focus on Slope and for the same I will need value of Z at every point. As of now I have XY coordinate and Angle and I wanted to find the Z coordinate.

Looking forward to hear the experts suggestion/direction.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. You talk about XY-coordinates and looking for a Z-coordinate: 3 coordinates (XYZ) only exist in 3d-space. Do you mean you have sides a & b and the angle (slope) and want to know the height at every point (or side c)? Or is XY the start coordinate? Maybe post a picture.

Comment: @marsze, Yes you got the point. I have size a&b and the angle (Slope) and want to know height at every angle. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

So, I guess it looks somewhat like this:

```
      /|
     / |
  x /  |
   /   | z
  /    |
 /     |
/γ)____|
     y
```

You might want to use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):

```
z = sqrt(x² + y² - 2 * x * y * cos(γ))
```

... or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) (at any offset ***s***):

```
z = ((y - s) / sin(90 - γ) * sin(γ)
```

---

*UPDATE:*

So, let's say  point `P1` is the start of your triangle (bottom left corner) and point `P2` is any point on the slope:

```
        /
    P2 .< P2.y
      /|
     / |
    /  |
   /   |
  .γ)__|___ 
P1     ^
       P2.x
```

`P2.x` goes from `P1.x` to `P1.x + <the width of your triangle>`. Now, the only thing you need is coordinate `y` of `P2`. And (knowing the slope/angle `γ`) you can get it with the formula from above:

```
P2.y = ((P2.x - P1.x) / sin(90 - γ) * sin(γ) + P1.y
```

Comment: yes exactly I want to implement this. Now think, on the slope I want to write 'ABC' so I will have X,Y coordinate of ABC on that slope, now I will need respective Z coordinate at every point so that I can shift the focus as per Z value so that I can write ABC on the slope.  So for a little think as a 3d object where ABC lies on the slope. Meanwhile I will try to implement this equation in the testing coding. Thanks Buddy :)

Comment: @KanzariyaSuresh : You are still confusing me with your X-Y-Z coordinates. Please, either talk about sides (a, b, c) or XY-coordinates! So, is my answer all you need? (it should) -> Mark it as your chosen answer! Do you need more? -> Please explain again! Was it helpful anyway? -> Vote it up! Thanks.

Comment: I will need XY-coordinates. Yes technically you got it right, I want to implement in terms of XY coordiante. Thanks.

Comment: @KanzariyaSuresh : I updated the post. This is all I can do for you, now you will have to do the rest yourself. Good luck.

Comment: Thank You for your time, Once I will implement the solution I will let you know.

Comment: @KanzariyaSuresh Alrigthy. If it worked for you, please select/upvote my answer. Thanks.